# Map Implementation Ruby retrieve values of key

Tags: ruby

How would I write a map implementation with a get function that lets me retrieve the value of a key at a particular time. t:0 A =1 t:2 A = 2 get(A, t:1) -> 1 get(A, t:3) -> 2

I know that this will involve a hash somewhere but I can figure out how to implement it.

Comment: can you provide more details on what you are looking for? I'm not sure I get it. Like a pseudo code version of what you want and a desired result.

Comment: Your question is premature. You need to try, and when you can't try further show us a minimal example of your effort with an explanation of why it doesn't do what you want. Asking us how to do it is asking for a tutorial. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]", along with "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)".

Answer (score 0):

I'm afread I misunderstand your question, if not correct please elaborate more and show us what you mean by time

First a hash of hashes

```
T = {0 => {A: 0}, 1 => {A: 1}, 2 => {A: 1}, 3 => {A: 3}}
T[0] # {:A=>0}
```

Then a method to get the value given the time and key

```
def get(key, time)
  T[time][key]
end

get(:A, 1) # 1
```

Is that what you want ?

Comment: Tossing out an answer when you're not sure what is being asked wastes your time. Instead ask for clarification then answer.